# Android Google Play Tabs with Sliding Toolbar

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar, sliding, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to have layout with a toolbar with internally an image and under the toolbar I need to have tabs like google play :

**under the collapsing toolbar like this**

[image]

**I need to have tabs like**

[image]

I know how to implement both of them distinctly but I don't know how to implement them together and let the tabs move (and keep under the toolbar) when the toolbar is moving.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I implemented them in the same time but it didn't work

Comment: May be this could help you https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

Comment: @user3706150 This is very similar of what I was thinking but I prefer just to have the simple tabs attached to the bottom of the toolbar, without particular animations or design